# Sum a range if value matches criteria where the range is produced using the intersect operator

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In my specific case, I'm trying to sum only positive numbers that fall within the intersection of my named ranges. However the intersect operator does not appear to work with the SUMIF function.

`=SUMIF(Master_Categories Remaining,">0")`

I believe this does not work because the Intersect Operator produces a list of cells rather than a range. Is there another way to accomplish this?

**EDIT: Sample Dataset**

```
Master_Categories|Remaining
cat 1            |1
                 |2
cat 2            |-1
                 |-2
                 |3
cat 3            |3
                 |4
cat 4            |-3
                 |-4
cat 5            |5
                 |5
```

`Master_Categories =!$1:$1,!$3:$3,!$6:$6,!$8:$8,!$10:$10`
`Remaining         =!$B:$B`

*Evaluate Formula Error*

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "intersect operator"? I'm not aware of such thing in Excel.

Comment: @MátéJuhász: See [Calculation operators and precedence / Reference operators](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/calculation-operators-and-precedence-36de9366-46fe-43a3-bfa8-cf6d8068eacc#tblID0EBBAACAAA).

Comment: MplsAmigo: I got it to work, exactly as you showed (Excel 2013).  Can you think of anything that you might have done to make it break?  Do ``=SUM(Remaining)`` and ``=SUMIF(Remaining,">0")`` work correctly?  Can you show us a MCVE (a *small*, reproducible example)?

Comment: @MátéJuhász: You might want to also see [Intersection Operator with Named Ranges - Excel Tips and Tricks - Excel TV](https://excel.tv/intersection-operator-with-named-ranges-excel-tips-and-tricks/).

Comment: That guidance is not clear. I think intersection operator works only where union works too (SUM, OR, AND...). You might try to evaluate your formula (formula - evaluate) and see how Excel interprets it.

Comment: **#MplsAmigo** Since you have not included sample data therefore it's difficult to justify the **Named Range**  you have used with the Formula whether intersects data range or not and if is has Single data range then it never meets the object!! Yes `SUMIF` can be used for intersection!!

Comment: **,,Cont** even if `Master_Categories` & `Remaining` are intersecting or not each other the Command Syntax is wrong in `SUMIF` Criteria comes first then the `SUM Range`!!

Comment: Okay, I added a relevant sample dataset and named ranges that produces the same error. I also included an image of the Evaluate Formula dialog.

Comment: Does anyone have insight into this?

Comment: if you put the equation in `SUMIFS()` , how will it look like?

Answer (score 1):

The formula, as is, is producing a pair of one line matrices - in its internal steps - that have the values of the cells in each range.

Nothing is presently being done to convert them to something that can be summed.

First, the Master_Categories Named Range. The idea would appear to be to only sum Remaining's if there is an entry in the matching Master_Categories cell for them. The approach in the formula is reminiscent of the standard "make a {1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1} style matrix" but all the steps to convert from the text being returned in the matrix to TRUE/FALSE entries and finally to the 1's and 0's is not being done. In this case, all the union operator is doing is producing a `#NULL!`.

So, create the matrix needed for that portion and force the value when no text is present to be 0:

```
=NOT(ISBLANK(Master_Categories))*1
```

does the trick. `ISBLANK()` tests for a blank yielding the opposite of what you need, then `NOT()` reverses that. The final step is to convert the text TRUE/FALSE values to 1's and 0's. Doing a simple, no other effect arithmetic operation, on them (" *1 " or " +0 ") does that.

Then the Remaining portion. Use the following for that portion:

```
=((Remaining>0)*1)*Remaining
```

The first bit tests each value against ">0" returning TRUE/FALSE values which are converted to 1's and 0's by the "times 1" part. The final part of this portion takes that resultant matrix of 1's and 0's and multiplies it by a matrix of the actual values in Remaining. This drops out the <0 items because their values in the 1's and 0's are 0's and zero times anything is 0. You then have a matrix of Remaining's actual values which are >0 and 0's.

Then "`SUM()`" everything (not `SUMIF()` because you did the selecting already):  it multiplies the two matrices (1/0's in the first part, actual column values and 0's in the second part) so the 1's from the first part "collect" the values from Remaining and sum them finally giving you your answer.

It does have to be a CSE formula:

```
{=SUM(NOT(ISBLANK(Master_Categories))*(Remaining>0)*Remaining*1)}
```

So... basically, Test * Test * Test (multiplication is the logical `AND` in arithmetic, and addition is the logical `OR`) gets the values of interest then `Sum()` finishes it off.

A sidenote:

You CAN do all of each part IN the Named Ranges (using the exact separate pieces shown earlier and the literal ranges in place of each name in them), rather than just define their cell ranges. Then the formula could be:

```
{=SUM(Master_Categories * Remaining)}
```

which you might prefer. (Still must be a CSE formula.)

One last note:  editing the formula (`F2`), highlighting portions, usually from the "inside-outward", and pressing `F9` to see how Excel evaluates them often shows a fairly different picture from what Formula Evaluator shows. Much the same, obviously, but as granular as you like. It can be very useful.

Edited to slightly simplify the formula. Many, seemingly arbitrary, times, changing arrays to 1's and 0's fails without enclosing parentheses and I have also always assumed one needed one "*1" (or "+0") PER matrix to change, but while seeing if the extra parentheses could be removed, I experimented and found a single "*1" for the entire multiplication string works just as well. Still CSE though... tantalizingly, when the entire inside formula is `F9'ed` down to the final matrix, `SUM()` gets the answer without CSE, but I cannot find a way to make it do so with the parts instead.